# Best method to fit a GEV distribution with generalised linear modelling of parameters?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, extreme-value

I need to fit a generalised extreme value distribution to my data but I want the ability to perform generalised linear modelling of the parameters, particularly the location. Can anyone recommend the best method/R package for doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Since (to my understanding) the GEV isn't exponential family, what do you intend when you say "generalized linear modelling"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new to R, but for my research I have to deal with extreme values, so maybe what I found can help you.

1. You need to install the `evd` package.
2. Then you can use the function `fgev` (assuming you are using generalized extreme value distribution) and specify the location that you want, like this:

   ```
   library(evd)
   M <- fgev(uvdata, location = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0)
   ```

The first argument is your data, then you can specify the other parameters you need.